# How to update database when using wild characters for example like 

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have column which consists of path  for example `\\Abc\F\E\record_123`, now i need to update the path in database where only one change i need to do is this:

`\\Abc\F\E\record_123`  = `\\Abc\F\G\record_123`  - i want to update E to G .

how to do that with update query in database?

Answer (score 1):

```
REPLACE('\Abc\F\E\record_123', '\E\', '\G\')
```

You have clear delimiters that allows you to pick out the bits you want to replace

Answer (score 0):

See [SQL Server string functions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx). REPLACE() would be a good candidate.